# Modularise Spring Boot application when migrating from Java 8 to Java 11

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot 2.0 web application, running on Java 8. It is working fine and I'm totally happy with it. However, I decided to migrate to Java 11 to start catching up with Java release cycle.

What are the criteria to decide whether to break down the application to modules or run it on the classpath?

Is modularising your application is the thing you should do asap or you should decide based on your needs?

Comment: This depends on the size of your application. If you're doing small Microservices there is no need for modularization IMHO.